# EmbeddedLdapRule with JUnit5

Tags: apache, ldap, junit5

Could someone help me port the EmbeddedLdapRule in JUnit5?  I tried with JUnit4 and it worked perfectly.   But Apached LDAP-API can't connect in JUnit5.

Basically, I like to bring up the embedded ldap and use the Apached LDAP-API to connect to it for Unit Test.

```
class EmbeddedLDAPServer implements BeforeEachCallback {
    private final String host;
    private final int    port;
    private final String adminPassword;
    private final String adminUser;
    private final String dsn;
    private final String ldifFilename;

    public EmbeddedLdapRule embeddedLdapRule;

    public EmbeddedLDAPServer(String host,
                              int port,
                              String adminUser,
                              String adminPassword,
                              String dsn,
                              String ldifFileName) {
        this.host = host;
        this.port = port;
        this.adminUser = adminUser;
        this.adminPassword = adminPassword;
        this.dsn = dsn;
        this.ldifFilename = ldifFileName;
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("dsn : " + dsn);
        System.out.println("port: " + port);
        System.out.println("ldif: " + ldifFilename);
        embeddedLdapRule = EmbeddedLdapRuleBuilder.newInstance()
                                                  .usingDomainDsn(dsn)
                                                  .bindingToAddress(host)
                                                  .bindingToPort(port)
                                                  .usingBindDSN(adminUser)
                                                  .usingBindCredentials(adminPassword)
                                                  .importingLdifs(ldifFilename)
                                                  .build();
    }
}
```

Register with:

```
    @RegisterExtension
    static EmbeddedLDAPServer embeddedLDAPServer = new EmbeddedLDAPServer(LDAP_HOST,
                                                                          LDAP_PORT,
                                                                          ADMIN_DN,
                                                                          ADMIN_PASSWORD,
                                                                          BASEDN,
                                                                          "users.ldif");
```

and it failed at attempting to connect:

```
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() throws LdapException {
        System.out.println("setup()");
        LdapConnectionConfig config = new LdapConnectionConfig();
        config.setLdapHost(LDAP_HOST);
        config.setLdapPort(LDAP_PORT);
        config.setName(ADMIN_DN);
        config.setCredentials(ADMIN_PASSWORD);
        connection = new LdapNetworkConnection(config);

        connection.bind();
        Assertions.assertTrue(connection.isConnected());
        Assertions.assertTrue(connection.isAuthenticated());
    }



Adding the JUnit4 @Rule

@Rule
public EmbeddedLdapRule embeddedLdapRule = EmbeddedLdapRuleBuilder.newInstance()
    .usingDomainDsn(BASEDN)
    .bindingToAddress(LDAP_HOST)
    .bindingToPort(LDAP_PORT)
    .usingBindDSN(ADMIN_DN)
    .usingBindCredentials(ADMIN_PASS)
    .importingLdifs("users.ldif")
    .build();
```

Comment: The JUnit 4 magic happens in the code of EmbeddedLdapRule. Please add this code to your question so that readers can suggest its translation into a Jupiter extension.

Comment: just added the JUnit4 @Rule code

Comment: The interesting part is in class ˋEmbeddedLdapRuleˋ itself. It probably does something before and after test invocation. That logic must be transferred to your new Jupiter extension. Just creating an instance of the rule does not help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I got it to work now after digging through the `EmbeddedLdapRule` code.

Comment: Maybe you can show your solution as answer. The next person with a similar question will appreciate it.